# Pass Vuejs $index to Laravel Session array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session

I created a form where some inputs are automatically added to the form based on the value from a select input. Ex. select has value 3, inserts 3 inputs, then if select gets value 1 the two last inputs are removed and remains only one input. I built this process with vuejs.

This form is part of a multipage form, and its data is stored in a session, so the user can go back and forward and data he inserted must be filled in the proper places.

The data from those automatically created inputs is saved into a session array ( Session::put(“stop_airport”) ) and to get an individual value, i must call something like this Session::get(“stop_airport.0”).

So...

How do i pass the $index variable from the vuejs loop “v-for” to laravel session array variable Session::get(“stop_airport.0”), replacing the 0(zero) by $index?

Or there is another way of doing this?

View

```
<div class="form-group{{$errors->has('stop_airport[0]') ? ' has-error' : ''}}" v-for="stop in stops" v-if="main.stops > '0'">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="control-form">Aeroporto de Escala</label>
         <input type="text" name="stop_airport[]" :placeholder="($index+1) +'ª Escala'" class="form-control airport-input" v-model="stop.airport" value="{{Session::get('stop_airport.0')}}">
         @if ($errors->has('stop_airport[0]'))
             <span class="help-block">
                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('stop_airport[0]') }}</strong>
             </span>
         @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Vuejs

```
new Vue({
        el:'#flight-details',
        data:{
            main:{
                stops:''
            },
            stops:[],
            oldStops:''
        },
        methods: {
            updateStops: function (event) {
                // diffrence between current and old stops values
                var dif = this.main.stops - this.oldStops;
                // if negative
                if(dif < 0){
                    dif *= -1;
                    var lgt = this.stops.length - 1;
                    var index = 0;
                    for(var i=0;i<dif;i++){
                        index = lgt - i;
                        this.stops.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                // if positive
                }else if(dif > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<dif;i++){
                        this.stops.push({
                            airport:""
                        });
                    }
                }
                // save current stops value
                this.oldStops = this.main.stops;
            },
        },
        ready: function(){
            this.updateStops();
        }
    });
```